# Converting \r\n to new line in plain text?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, newline

I'm executing some commands on command line and printing the results on the UI, the command line output is filled with \r\n, any ideas on how to convert it to new line in plain text using javascript ?

```
resp = resp.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n | \r\n\r\n)/g, '<br />');
```

tried to use 
 and append it to div.innerHTM, but thats not clean.

How the command line output looks :
[image]

How it looks on my UI if i use div.innerHTML after replacing \r\n with 
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: `"but thats not clean."` I have no clue what that means.

Comment: @epascarello updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: well does not look like you are replacing everything correctly.

Comment: Why is regexp not just `.replace*(/\n\r/g, "<br/>")`

Comment: even with that, the output nowhere looks close to what it looks like on the command line. I would like it to be readable. is there any other approach for this ?

Comment: It seems that what you really want to do is convert plain text to HTML which involves more than newlines as `>` should be converted to `&gt;` and so on. Here's a start: https://github.com/gbourne1/text2HTML/blob/master/text2HTML.js

Comment: even plain text would do, i can put it in a textnode and append it to the div as its child, but i dont know how to replace \r\n with newlines in plain text aswell.

Comment: So set it into a textarea....

Comment: I would use a <pre> element, then tabs and Newline will display correct.

Comment: @PoulBak would that work in a textNode ?